# What is a Linux kernel arm64 boot executable image

Tags: linux, qemu, arm64

I am learning how to work with QEMU and have a .img file for a system firmware image.
Running file on this returns that the file is a linux kernel arm64 boot executable image.
Also, I tried running binwalk on the file, but no file system was recovered. I a bit confused here on how to emulate this using QEMU. What exactly is a linux kernel arm64 boot executable image and how can I use this with QEMU?

Comment: Hm, you did not write full name of the image file and its properties. If it is really _linux kernel arm64 boot executable image_ than it is the core of the Linux OS. Usually its size is about some megabytes. You need to get an initramfs file which contents the basic _filesystem_. Both these files are loaded into the RAM and the kernel makes the first wake up of the hardware, looking for the root disk volume to be mounted. But the boot process is much more complicated to be described here.

Comment: It's a firmware image file for an IoT device that's running on Zephyr OS. The format of the image is raw according to QEMU and the size is nearly 1 MB. I am trying to both understand what it means in this context to be a boot executable Image and if it is even possible to emulate this?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6139952/what-is-the-booting-process-for-arm) might help. ARM boards do not have a single way of booting. See the first comment on the question to have an idea of what you are up to.